# Java Map<Entity1, Entity2> mapping to the database using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa

In a project I'm working on, there seems to be a problem mapping a (Hash)Map to the database using JPA.

The Map (named 'racers', within the entity 'Race') consists of key-value-pairs < User, Racestats >, both custom entities in JEE.

The map is annotated by "@ElementCollection".

When trying to persist the map to the database, an error is given: "Data truncation: Data too long for column 'RACERS'".

When checking the database, we see a table 'Race_RACERS' is created, which consists of three columns: two bigints (representing the id of the Race object and the User object) and one varchar, which contains the Racestats object.

Of course, this last column should also contain references to the Racestats, instead of embedding these Racestats objects.

We have already tried fixing the issue using several other annotations, but none of them seem to work.

Could anyone please provide us with the correct syntax to persist our objects.

Keys will obviously be unique in each map, but within different Race objects, the Maps could contain the same key.

No 2 values will ever be the same. Even within different Race objects, maps will never contain the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the information about your use cases, but it looks to me like it would be simpler to put the User reference inside the Racestats entity, e.g.:

```
@Entity
public class Race {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="race")
    Set<Racestats> racestats;
}

@Entity
public class Racestats {
    @ManyToOne
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    Race race;

    // Other race stats fields
    ...
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to get the RaceStat for a certain User. If implemented like you suggest, we'd have to loop over all RaceStats to find out which one belongs to the correct User. This doesn't seem ideal to me...

Comment: Would you know of a correct way to solve my problem while keeping the User-RaceStats-Map? When simply giving the Map a OneToMany annotation, we get EclipseLink exceptions: "The table [RACESTATS] is not present in this descriptor." and "A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.".

Comment: Sorry if I don't answer your question, but I don't see a way to do that using a Map of entities. That map may be a good construct in java, but it is not a standard way to map your entities to the database with JPA.